# same CommunicationException in WCF with two different scenario

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, exception

I am creating a WCF web service using EF 5 & .NET 4. Now I am done with web service and when I try to consume the service from service project & Windows 8 app project, I am getting the **same** exception in two different scenario. The exception is given below.

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   `http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/FcpService/DataServices/FcpServices`.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.

**Scenario 1** : Getting error while `getting` data. `Insertion/deletion/updation` working just fine.

I am using `FcpDataModel.Context.tt` & `FcpDataModel.tt`. Code generation strategy is set to `None`.

**Scenario 2** : Getting error while `insertion/deletion/updation`. `Getting` data working just fine.

I am NOT using `FcpDataModel.Context.tt` & `FcpDataModel.tt`. Code generation strategy is set to `Default`, so it generates new classes in file `FcpDataModel.Designer.cs`. The EDMX file name is `FcpDataModel.edmx`.

Anyone have idea how to solve this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for scenario 1 is probably a serialization error. try to disable proxy on EF Context.

For scenario 2 I don't understand why it work for getting data ?